# End of File error when trying to get response from a url and parsing the JSON with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging

I keep getting this error:

```
Errno::ECONNRESET in SearchController#create

Connection reset by peer
```

and

```
EOFError in SearchController#create

end of file reached
```

I'm trying to get the response from Google's API and then parse the JSON with ruby. Here's my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'net/https'

def create
  @search = params[:search][:search]
  base_url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0"
  url = "#{base_url}&q=#{@search}&rsz=8&start=0"
  resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
  data = resp.body

  result = JSON.parse(data)

  if result.has_key? 'Error'
     raise "web service error"
  end
  return result
end
```

and `resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))` seems to be the line giving me the error. How can I fix this?

Here's the first part of the full trace:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `sysread'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `rbuf_fill'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:62:in `timeout'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:93:in `timeout'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2020:in `read_status_line'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2009:in `read_new'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1050:in `request'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:948:in `request_get'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:380:in `get_response'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:379:in `get_response'
app/controllers/search_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

Comment: Does it work any better if you use the `http://...` URL instead of `https://...`?

Comment: yes............. it works if I use http

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I recommend using [`Open::URI`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/open-uri/1.9.2/frames) unless you need the lower-level routine's granularity or control:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

def create
  search = params[:search][:search]
  base_url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0"

  stream = open("#{base_url}&q=#{search}&rsz=8&start=0")
  raise 'web service error' if (stream.status.first != '200')

  JSON.parse(stream.read)
end
```

Open::URI automatically handles redirects and, better yet for this purpose, handles setting up the HTTPs connection for you.

If you want to use Net::HTTP this will work:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'net/http'

def create(search)
  base_url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0"
  url = "#{base_url}&q=#{search}&rsz=8&start=0"
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  connection = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 443)
  connection.use_ssl = true

  resp = connection.request_get(uri.path + '?' + uri.query)

  if resp.code != '200'
     raise "web service error"
  end

  JSON.parse(resp.body) 
end

puts create('ruby')
```

The difference is that I'm telling Net::HTTP to open a SSL connection using port 443, which is where I think your code is failing. Also, I'm looking for the success status code '200', which you might want to check, and then react if you got a redirect.

Comment: Should change the require 'net/http' to https .. http does not have the use_ssl= method. iT only has use_ssl? method.

Answer (score -1):

It might be a problem with Net::HTTP itself. Try using httparty: http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

Comment: The problem isn't with Net::HTTP. It's that he didn't set the connection up correctly.